# F# casting an int

Tags: casting, f#, type-safety

This is a quite trivial thing but I am really struggling to get this to work. I want to cast the results of `sqrt n` where `n` is of type `int64` and finally pass that to a function that takes an `int` but I am really struggling to get a decent solution of it, this is the way I came up with but this is hideous and I can't believe that something that is so trivial to do in for example C# should be so hard in F#.

```
n 
|> float 
|> sqrt 
|> int 
|> function
```

Comment: You want to convert int64 to int32 ?
let bignum = 155556L
let myint = int(bignum);;

Comment: The C# version only saves you a single cast from `long` to `double`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is F# - if you don't have what you want, write a function. For instance:

```
let inline sqrttoint n =
    (int (sqrt (float n)))

n |> sqrttoint |> function
```

On top of that it works on anything that can cast to `float`.

The main issue of C# vs F# is that you are used to C# where numeric types are auto-promoted whereas F# wants you to care about the type of most everything and changes in type need to be more explicit.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I figured that it really has to do with a lot of what I am used to vs how things are done differently in F#. But it is quite a bit frustrating.

Comment: Yes, it is frustrating at times, but when you start using your functions as first class objects and use partial function application you'll find that the type strength is a big win for code correctness. The equivalent C# code (int)Math.Sqrt(someInt64) will do pretty much exactly what I have up there anyway and is pretty much the same amount of effort to type in. Different language, different idioms.